# How to create modal list in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to recreate a modal list popover in Swift, similar to the ones found in other several popular applications. See below for examples.

[image: Instagram]
[image: Twitter]

My current attempt looks like this:

```
@IBAction func showListOptions(sender: AnyObject) {
    // segue set to "Present Modally"
    // Presentation set to "Over Current Context"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowListItems", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.3)
}
```

The next view is a regular `ViewController` with a few buttons with their layout relative to the bottom of the screen.

A few things to note, when I set the `Presentation` style of the `segue` to "Full Screen", the background turns full black (instead of the desired alpha (rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)).

Setting the `Presentation` to "Over Current Context", I at least get the alpha color background, but I'm still able to click around on my tabbar at the bottom... which then turns my modal back to a black screen.

Help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? In both of your examples, those are `UIAlertView` of type `ActionSheet` which are provided as part of the iOS API. An example can be found here: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/action-sheet-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: Thank you! To answer your first question -- because I'm learning ;) Your answer was helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pbush25 - what I am really looking for is a `UIAlertController` of type `ActionSheet`. This ultimately does all the work for you :)

The tutorial (written in Swift for iOS 8) can be found here http://ioscreator.com/tutorials/action-sheet-tutorial-ios8-swift

Answer (score 0):

In the second example is an UIActionSheet (easier to implement). 
The first one is an UIView with low alpha (about a BlackColor with 0.5 alpha) with an UITableView constrained to bottom, trailing and leading. That with a keyframe animation. Using a UIViewController isn't the easiest approx. on this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 7.0 and up then you can do UIActionSheet

```
let myActionSheet = UIActionSheet()
myActionSheet.delegate = self
myActionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Add event")
myActionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("close")
myActionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = 1
myActionSheet.showInView(self.view)

func actionSheet(myActionSheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
    if(myActionSheet.tag == 1){
        if (buttonIndex == 0){
            println("Do something")
        }
    }
}
```

if you are targeting iOS 8.0 and up then do UIAlertController

```
let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
let otherAction = UIAlertAction(title: "other", style: .Default, handler: otherHandler)
myAlertController.addAction(cancelAction)
myAlertController.addAction(otherAction)
self.presentViewController(myAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

func otherHandler(alertAction: UIAlertAction) {
    //Do something when other button is tapped
}
```